# Quick way to see references between workspace projects in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have imported a Maven project in Eclipse that I'm currently not very familiar with. For example, I don't have an overview of how the modules/workspace projects reference each other.

So, I can now open the "Maven Dependencies" library of every project and check which other workspace projects are listed there. I'll eventually get an overview over the dependencies, but this is a quite tedious process.

Isn't there an easier way to learn about dependencies between the projects in the Eclipse workspace?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the dependency hierarchy of the poms, which is searchable (and hierarchical).